# Is this subject singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

I have a simple thing, but it confused me.

> *The nature of convergences of topological relations of segment adjacencies* can be derived from graphs.

I want to know whether the subject of the above sentence is singular or plural, as I am now confused and feeling it might be plural.  Any comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's singular.  The subject is one fairly large noun phrase, *the nature of convergences of topological relations of segment adjacencies*, but don't be fooled by all the extra words: the head of this noun phrase is the noun *nature*, and since *nature* is singular, so is the entire noun phrase.

Comment: many thanks. you said the point.. nature.. thanks again